# Age not working as expected when selecting from jquery date picker and tabbing off dob field

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I am trying to calculate age from my model using the date picker I also have to account for the user tabbing out but its not working on either.

```
<div class="card-body">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOB)
    <input asp-for="DOB" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="DOB" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>                                       

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Age)
    <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />

    <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

In My Model I have

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = " Date of Brith is Required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
public int Age {
       get {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
            int age = now.Year - GetAge(DOB);
            if (age == 0) return 0;
            if (DOB > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
            return age;
        }
    }

    public static int GetAge(DateTime birthDate) {
        DateTime n = DateTime.Now; // To avoid a race condition around midnight
        int age = n.Year - birthDate.Year;
        if (age == 0) return 0;
            
        if (n.Month < birthDate.Month || (n.Month == birthDate.Month && n.Day < birthDate.Day))
            age--;

        return age;
   }
```

But when I look a the page its just outputting zero even after selecting a date. I am using jQuery JavaScript Library v3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to calculate age from my model using the date picker I also have to account for the user tabbing out but its not working on either.

You need to know the getter accessor is invoked by creating the instance in the server side.What you did is just a client side operation so that it could not work.

For your requirement,you could use jQuery to invoke the method:

***Model:***

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Date of Brith is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
            int age = GetAge(DOB);     //change this...
            if (age == 0) return 0;
            if (DOB > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
            return age;
        }
    }

    public static int GetAge(DateTime birthDate)
    {
        DateTime n = DateTime.Now; 
        int age = n.Year - birthDate.Year;
        if (age == 0) return 0;

        if (n.Month < birthDate.Month || (n.Month == birthDate.Month && n.Day < birthDate.Day))
            age--;

        return age;
    }
}
```

***View(`Home/Index.cshtml`):***

```
@model TestModel
<div class="card-body">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOB)
    <input asp-for="DOB" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="DOB" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Age)
    <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />

    <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $("#DOB").change(function () {
        var date = this.value;
        window.location.href = "/Home/Index?date=" + date;
    });
</script>
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(string date)
    {
        if (date != null)
        {
            var model = new TestModel()
            {
                DOB = DateTime.Parse(date)
            };
            return View(model);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

***Result***(The disadvantage is that this would change the request url):

[image]

**The second way**,if you do not want to change the request url:

***View:***

```
<script>
    $("#DOB").change(function () {
        var date = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/Index?date=' + date,
            type: 'Get',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Age').val(data);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

***Controller:***

```
public IActionResult Index(string date)
{
    if (date != null)
    {
        var model = new TestModel()
        {
            DOB = DateTime.Parse(date)
        };
        return Ok(model.Age);
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Another way** is entirely using jQuery to caculate the age instead of invoking server side code:

```
<script>
    $("#DOB").change(function () {           
        var dob = this.value;
        dob = new Date(dob);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        $('#Age').val(age);
    });
</script>
```

Or:

```
<script>
    $("#DOB").change(function () {
        var now = new Date();
        var age = GetAge($("#DOB").val());
        if (age == 0) return 0;
        $("#Age").val(age);
    });
    function GetAge(birthDate) {
        var n = new Date()// To avoid a race condition around midnight
        var birth = new Date(birthDate)
        var age = n.getFullYear() - birth.getFullYear();
        if (age == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n.getMonth() < birth.getMonth() || (n.getMonth() == birth.getMonth() && n.getDay() < birth.getDay())) {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    }
</script>
```

***Model:***

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Date of Brith is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: amazing answer as always